# postgres subselect using field value as schema name

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to make a subselect from a schema where the name of the schema is taken from the value of one of the fields in the main select?  Kinda like this:

```
create schema a;
create table a.foo(id int);
create schema b;
create table b.foo(id int);

create table public.schemalist (schemaname text);
insert into schemalist values ('a'),('b');

select 
schemaname,
(select count(*) from  schemaname.foo)
from public.schemalist;
```

but somehow telling Postgres to count up the `foo` table in the `schemaname` schema in the second column...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create `SQL` statement based on the data stored within your Model. I believe the only way to achieve this is to use PL/pgSQL function and build (and execute) dynamic statements inside.

I would double checked the design, though. I used to do smilar things a couple of times myself, but best solution in each case was to get rid of this functionality.

---

**EDIT** Please, note, that using schema-per-customer design is not a bad practice, I advocate this approach myself. My point is — it's not possible to use catalog details to specify which tables to query in a single statement. SQL is declarative, i.e. DBMS will do what you have explicitly mentioned in the query.

Several approaches how to fix your situation:

1. Create a dedicated schema for you as service registrar, and create and maintain a bunch of views, that will span all your clients' schemas tables. Like, if you're interested in checking orders, do smth along:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW registrar.all_orders AS
   SELECT * FROM cust1.orders
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM cust2.orders
   UNION ALL ...
   ```

   For each table of interest create and maintain a dedicated view. By “maintain” I mean — procedure of introducing new customers into the system should also update all registrar views.
2. Create a function to produce query you're interested in dynamically again, within the registrar's schema. This might be tricky, as you will not be able to create such a function to be trully universal:

   - you'll have to either define it like `RETURNS TABLE` and explicitly define columns,
   - or you can define it like `RETURNS SETOF record`, but in this case you'll be forced to provide
     column specification when you invoke the function.

Both of these provide you with the way to refer to a single object in the database (use known identifier) and obtain a list of related values via this abstraction.

I would go for #1 in case you have stable number of clients (schemas) and for #2 in case you add and/or remove clients quite often.

Comment: We're using a separate schema for each of our customers.  The issue arose when trying to gather statistics across all customers.  This design allows us to take advantage `search path` functionality, and I was under the impression it was a best-practice application of the use of schemas.  Doesn't this seem a good fit?

Comment: I'm now left-joining on a temp table much like your approach in suggestion 1.  Thanks